# Set up a NSMutableArray of objects to match a string value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using the value of two sliders as the first search criteria.

---

Now I want a second criteria. I have a

```
NSMutableArray *suitsArray;
```

which is containing up to 10 words, or it could be empty (0 words). Example of array:

```
2012-08-12 03:13:14.825 App[4595:f803] The content of array is(
mushroom,
grill,
pizza
)
```

---

What I want is this:

If suitsArray is like above, containing words **mushroom**, **grill** and **pizza**

and the "Suits" value in a dictionary is: "This wine suits **mushroom** dishes, **grilled** food, **pizza** and chicken."

This dictionary is added to searchResultsArray, same with all other dictionaries where "Suits" value containing words **mushroom**, **grill** and **pizza**.

But if suitsArray is empty of objects, skip this critera.

But I'm not sure how to write the code for it. Can you help me on it?

---

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{  

    resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *object in allObjectsArray)

    {

    NSString *objectPrice = [object objectForKey:@"75 cl price"];

    NSString *suitsString = // the words in suitsArray
    NSString *objectSuits = [object objectForKey:@"Suits"];


    BOOL priceConditionGood = YES;
    if (minPrisSlider.value <= maxPrisSlider.value && (winePrice.floatValue < minPrisSlider.value || winePrice.floatValue > maxPrisSlider.value))
        priceConditionGood = NO;
    if (priceConditionGood)
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:object];
     }


    ResultsTableViewController *nextController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsController"];
    nextController.objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:resultObjectsArray];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line: NSString *suitsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", suitsArray];

Comment: But I think that will make suitsString look just like when you do a log of an array, meaning it will have any parentheses and curly brackets in there as well. Your rangeOfString: method looks backwards -- you're trying to find suitsString in objectSuits which will never happen because of the problem I mentioned first.  I'm not sure what you want the search to be -- are you looking to see if any of the strings in suitsArray are in objectSuits or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, I want to see is if the strings in suitsArray are existing in objectSuits string. And add the matches to resultObjectsArray.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to make NSString *suitsString = the words in suitsArray, and compare it with the objectSuits, and add the positive matches to resultObjecsArray.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to see if suitsArray contains the string objectSuits, rather than using rangeOfString.

```
if ([suitsArray containsObject:objectSuits]);
    [resultObjectsArray addObject:object];
```

After edit:  I think I understand now. This method looks at each word in suitsArray, and if it finds any of them in objectSuits, then object is added to the resultObjectArray.

```
    for (NSString *aWord in suitsArray) {
        if ([objectSuits rangeOfString:aWord].length == aWord.length) {
            [resultObjectArray addObject:objectSuits];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Second Edit:  After further thought, the above code has a flaw in the logic that may or may not be important -- because it uses rangeOfString it will find words inside other words.  So, if objectSuits was "This wine goes well with cheesecake" and suitsArray contained the word cheese, it would find a match (I can't imagine a wine that would be good with cheese would be good with cheesecake). So, here is a better solution, I think, that breaks objectSuit up into individual words and puts them into a set. suitsArray is also converted to a set, so that we can use intersectsSet: to find if there are any common words.

```
NSCharacterSet *sepSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,.;"];
    NSArray *words = [objectSuits componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:sepSet];
    NSSet *objectSuitsWords = [NSSet setWithArray:words];
    NSSet *suitsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:suitsArray];
    BOOL ans = [suitsSet intersectsSet:objectSuitsWords];
```

So, if ans is 1, then that object should be added to the results array. Notice that sepSet starts with a space and includes a comma, period, and semicolon. There might be other things you might want to include, but I think this should work in most cases.

Comment: Edited my question. What I actually want is what you said in comment: to see if objectSuits, ("Suits" key's value), is containing the words from suitsArray. I want these objects added to results.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand -- So any words in objectSuits that match any word in suitsArray, you want added to results (not matching the whole string, but individual words)? An example might help.

Comment: If suitsArray contains the words: "**steak**", "**cheese**". And an object (dictionary) has the key "Suits" with the value like: "This wine is suitable for **steak**, **cheese**tables and mushrooom." Then this object is added to results.

Comment: Thanks a lot - just what I needed! Though, I actually do want it to find the word inside other words too, like "cheesecake" is positive match. Cheesecake would not be in the string anyways, but "cheesetable" and "grillED" could be, so "cheese" and "grill" should give a match for these words, even though it COULD give unlogic results in some cases it's better than excluding them. Again - thank you 1000 times!